# Index is not being used on a view with WHERE CONTAINS clause

Tags: oracle, view, indexing

I created a table and one of the columns is address.  I then created a view with a WHERE CONTAINS clause that states select can only be performed on address that contain a specific word.

I then created an index of the address column on the original table.

It says index created.

When I type

```
select * from myview
```

It says

```
drg-10599: column is not indexed.
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: What was the exact statement you used to create the index?  Did you create an Oracle Text index?  Or did you just create a regular old b-tree index?  Or did you create some other sort of index?

Comment: create index addressindex on table_a(address);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to create an Oracle Text index, not a standard b-tree index.  There are quite a few options for [creating and maintaining Oracle Text indexes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/ind.htm) that you should really read through in order to figure out exactly what options you want to use.

The simplest possible DDL statement would be

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON table_a(address) 
       INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;
```

Comment: That indextype worked just fine but I will read though that link to see if it is the best.  I appreciate the help on this Justin!